# pass object or object id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, activerecord

Given the following code, which **enroll** method is better and why? Or should this code be improved some other way altogether?

My idea of "better" for the above basically boils down to 1) most philosophically correct (best practices) and 2) most efficient/performant.

```
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments # basically a join table
  has_many :students, :source => :user, :through => :enrollments
  def enroll_this_way(student)
    self.enrollments << Enrollment.new(:course_id => self.id, :student_id => student.id)
  end
  # OR
  def enroll_that_way(student_id)
    self.enrollments << Enrollment.new(:course_id => self.id, :student_id => student_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: i would prefer the comparison against the object. but both should translate to similar performance.

Comment: The only reason to pass an integer is if you somehow have that number without creating the object. But if you already have the object, just pass it. Object creation is going to be the longest part of the code.

Comment: @DGM chances are I will most times have the student.id but I thought there might be some more important consideration (design pattern, best practice, etc.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def enroll_this_way(student)
  self.enrollments.build :student => student
end
```

Comment: This is better for a number of reasons, most of all being concise.

Answer (score 2):

Both are probably not perfect. `course#enrollments<<(object, …)` sets the foreign keys on enrollment objects, so you don't need to set `:course_id` on `enrollment`, alternatively you don't need to call `course#enrollments<<(object, …)` if foreign key is already set, you just call `enrollment#save`.

As @zed_0xff pointed to, you can just call `course#enrollments#build` (or better `course#enrollments.create` if you want changes to persist to database).

Besides you can safely omit `self`. There are no ambiguities as to what `enrollments` and `id` are.

Highly recommended [Rails Guides: 4.3 has_many Association Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference)

**Edit:** I just realized that I didn't answer the OP question. There is no difference at all.